# How to get Total reach using facebook insight Graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

anyone can help on facebook insights? I'm trying to get the Total Reach using facebook graph API.

Here's my example:

http://www.screencast.com/t/1deguhkEuMb

I've been trying these following metrics:

- /page_impressions_frequency_distribution
- /page_impressions_viral_frequency_distribution

But I still can't get the right value for the Total Reach.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the metric /post_impressions_unique
This will return the number of people who saw your Page post

Just tested it and the response object contains:

"title": "Lifetime Post Total Reach", 
"description": "Lifetime: The total number of people your Page post was served to. (Unique Users)"

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights

Comment: Do you know how can I get the total reach for the previous 7 days for example? As far as I know you can get the reach using the post_impressions_unique metric. The problem is that I don't know how to find out which posts where seen in the previous 7 days ?